# What is the default value for `maximumMessageSize` in URLSessionWebSocketTask?

Tags: ios, websocket, urlsession

What is the default value for [`URLSessionWebSocketTask.maximumMessageSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionwebsockettask/3181203-maximummessagesize#discussion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an iOS 17.0 simulator the default is 1048576 bytes or 1.048576 MB.